# "Error: unrecognized arguments" during easy_install

Tags: python, python-2.7, easy-install

After installing Anaconda2 I need to install additional python package SMOP. According to manual of package itself https://github.com/victorlei/smop I need to do 
  `$ easy_install smop --user`

Windows answers with this message:

```
Searching for smop

Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/smop/

Best match: smop 0.29

Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/52/f3/ec2f6ab31717bbf9e38040f9937febc2be43d6aac2be782250b617d287c2/smop-0.29.tar.gz#md5=732047fbcfe788a09fbc7f780ac28c1a

Processing smop-0.29.tar.gz

Writing c:\users\sergey\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-z5ebhu\smop-0.29\setup.cfg

Running smop-0.29\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\sergey\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-z5ebhu\smop-0.29\egg-dist-tmp-llgmp5

usage: 

smop [options][file.m ...file.m][-l file.py...]

    or

smop [options] library.tar [-l file.py...]

smop: error: unrecognized arguments: -q --dist-dir c:\users\sergey\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-z5ebhu\smop-0.29\egg-dist-tmp-llgmp5

error: Setup script exited with 2
```

Can you help with proper installation?

Comment: having the same issue here on MacOS and Ubuntu